# Indoor walk in Apple Watch how to use

Tags: apple-watch

Can I keep Indoor walk on all day as I am a housewife and have do lot of walking up and down at home

Comment: Yes, why don't you try?

Comment: Yes I tried. It shows more calories burnt then the normal

Comment: Well, that was to be expected, right?